# Pass file from Javascript upload to PHP

Tags: javascript, file, upload, status, progress

I'm working on a script to let the user upload a file and sees a upload status and the file is then saved on the server.

The problem is that I cannot use the php api. So I was thinking to upload the file with javascript where I can easly get the upload status but then I want to pass the file to php and save it.

Is this possible?

This is the javascript code to upload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<title>Upload Files using XMLHttpRequest</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fileSelected() {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
        if (file) {
            var fileSize = 0;
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
            else
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

            document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
            document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
            document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "UploadHandler.ashx");
        xhr.send(fd);
    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
            document.getElementById('prog').value = percentComplete;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
    }

    function uploadComplete(evt) {
        /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
        alert(evt.target.responseText);
    }

    function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
    }

    function uploadCanceled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <label for="fileToUpload">
            Select a File to Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" />
    </div>
    <div id="fileName">
    </div>
    <div id="fileSize">
    </div>
    <div id="fileType">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="progressNumber">
    </div>
    <progress id="prog" value="0" max="100.0"></progress>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ! exactly whant I needed. now SSL...

Answer (score 9):

I have a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/2410898) on this. It uses `xhr.send(FormData)` and shows minimal code
to handle the file in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Make an AJAX request to a PHP file, send the uploaded file properties like name, etc. and let it open that, move that, rename that or whatever needed. It should works, huh?

did I understood your question correctly?

**Sample Code:**

In Javascript:

```
// xhr
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "file_handler.php";
var file_data = "name=mypic.jpg&size=123&othe=etc";
http.open("POST", url, true);

// headers
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", file_data.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}

http.send(file_data);
```

In `file_handler.php`:

```
// file data
$file_data = $_POST['file_data'];

// working on the file
$temp_dir = 'usr/upload/';
$new_dir = 'usr/photos/';

// new unique name
$new_name = time() . '_' . $file_data['name'];

// copy?
if (copy($temp_dir . $file_data['name'], $new_dir . $new_name)) {
    unlink($temp_dir . $file_data['name']);
}

// rename?
rename($temp_dir . $file_data['name'], $temp_dir . $new_name);

// delete old file?
unlink($temp_dir . $file_data['name']);

// do whatever else needed here ...
// echo some JSON data to interact with your client-side JS code, maybe ...
```

Comment: Do you have a example code, so its easier to understand for me